# React - Carbon Design System - Transition in right sidebar not working

Tags: reactjs, high-order-component, carbon-design-system

### I'm trying to use Carbon Design System for a project, and I need some help with the UI Shell.

The transition of the right sidebar is not working properly.

#### Here is the working example, see how smooth it opens and closes ([see live example](https://pec0w.csb.app/)):

[image: working example]

#### Here is the example with issues. There's no transition ([see live example](https://jz7rz.csb.app/)):

[image: example with issues]

#### I think it's related to how High Order Components work. Here's my theory:

`HeaderPanel` is being rendered inside the `HeaderContainer`, which is a High Order Component.
When the state variable `switchCollapsed` changes, the `HeaderContainer` is rendered entirely again.
So this would explain why there's no transition.
**I'm new to React, and this theory is based on my React knowledge until now. Please correct me if I'm wrong**

#### Here's a piece of the code of the second example (simplified for the brevity of this post). See the [entire code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/left-and-right-panel-jz7rz?)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleSwitch = this.toggleSwitch.bind(this);
    this.state = { switchCollapsed: true };
  }

  toggleSwitch() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      switchCollapsed: !state.switchCollapsed
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <HeaderContainer
          render={({ isSideNavExpanded, onClickSideNavExpand }) => (
            <>
              <Header aria-label="IBM Platform Name">
                <HeaderMenuButton
                  onClick={onClickSideNavExpand}
                  isActive={isSideNavExpanded}
                />
                <HeaderGlobalBar>
                  <HeaderGlobalAction onClick={this.toggleSwitch}>
                    <UserAvatar20 />
                  </HeaderGlobalAction>
                </HeaderGlobalBar>
                <HeaderPanel
                  aria-label="Header Panel"
                  expanded={!this.state.switchCollapsed}
                />
                <SideNav
                  aria-label="Side navigation"
                  expanded={isSideNavExpanded}
                >
                  <SideNavItems>
                  </SideNavItems>
                </SideNav>
              </Header>
              <StoryContent />
            </>
          )}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

#### Moreover, if I change the property on React Dev Tools, the transition work!

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find solution?

Comment: @kl123 no, I've changed jobs and I don't even remember if I did something to mitigate the problem.